# PHP inpreter not working in specific virtual host

Tags: php, macos, apache, virtualhost

Working on Mac OS 10.9 I have successfully configured several virtual hosts for Apache 2.2 that work fine with PHP 5.4.

The latest virtual host should contain a Typo3 installation. It seems that the apache configuration is working (I can access the *.txt files), but the php interpreter refuses to work, so when I call the project with the browser, the index.php is being downloaded instead of being interpreted. The other projects still work fine.

vhost.conf:

```
NameVirtualHost neurobat.devel.local:80
<VirtualHost neurobat.devel.local:80>
    Servername neurobat.devel.local
    DocumentRoot /Users/MAC14/WebProjects/www/neurobat/www/neurobat1.net/typo3

    <Directory "/Users/MAC14/WebProjects/www/neurobat/www/neurobat1.net/typo3">
            Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride None
            DirectoryIndex index.php
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
    </Directory>
    AddType application/x-httpd-php .php
</VirtualHost>
```

Example of a file that is downloaded instead of being executed - phpinfo.php:

```
<?php phpinfo(); ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to update the filepermissions.